# EntityCommandCompilationException with Include method

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 4 tables in my database :

**Table1**
*idTable1*

**Table2**
idTable2
*#idTable1*

**Table3**
*idTable3*
*#idTable2*

**Table4**
*idTable4*
*#idTable2*

When I use the following instruction I have an EntityCommandCompilationException :

```
dbcontext.table1.Include("table2.table3").Include("table2.table4").Where(x => x.idTable1 == 1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Using lambda expressions have the same result :

```
dbcontext.table1.Include(x => x.table2.Select(y => y.table3)).Include(x => x.table2.Select(y => y.table4)).Where(x => x.idTable1 == 1).FirstOrDefault();
```

I have try only with "Include("table2.table3")" then only with "Include("table2.table4")" and it work perfectly.

I'm a beginner with entityframework and I don't have more idea to solve that issue, hope you can help me.

Regards

Edit :

Exception message : "An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details."

InnerException :  "the specified method is not supported" and sometimes just "null"

StackTrace :

```
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree)
   at System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbCommandTree commandTree)
   at System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Prepare(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree, Type elementType, MergeOption mergeOption, Span span, ReadOnlyCollection`1 compiledQueryParameters, AliasGenerator aliasGenerator)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__1[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at MyProjectServer_BLL.Implementation_EF.Table1_EF._getTable1(Int32 idTable1) dans c:\MyProject\MyProjectServer_BLL\Implementation_EF\Table1_EF.cs:ligne 43
   at MyProjectServer_BLL.Base.Table1_Base.getTable1(Int32 idTable1) dans c:\MyProject\MyProjectServer_BLL\Base\Table1_Base.cs:ligne 45
   at MyProject_ConsoleServer.Program.Main(String[] args) dans c:\MyProject\MyProject_ConsoleServer\Program.cs:ligne 62
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: What's the exception message (and stack trace)?

Comment: I have update my firt post. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

No need to give `Include` in table1.

but when you will work with the other table, then it is needed. for example

```
dbcontext.table2.Include("table1").Where(x => x.idTable2 == 1).FirstOrDefault();
```

actually Include is needed in one to many relationship.

Comment: My request on table1 include only "table2.table3" and "table2.table4", not "table1".

Comment: are there two tables in table2.table3 or is it a single table?